# Is it possible to have "public/global" fields in Julia structs?

Tags: julia

In Julia it is possible to have public fields in functions for instance

```
function foo(arg)
  global a = arg
  a
end
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar using Julia structures. 
For instance what I would like to do is:

```
julia> struct foobarfoo
       global a
       end

julia>

julia> test = foobarfoo(1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching foobarfoo(::Int64)
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0

julia> a
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
```

Instead of:

```
julia> struct foobarfoo
   a
   end

julia> test = foobarfoo(1)
foobarfoo(1)

julia> test.a
1

julia>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the short answer is no but you may be able to achieve what you want using the `@unpack` macro of [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl).